# Does Cassandra support many database in one server?

Tags: database, django, nosql, cassandra

I've started learning using Django with Cassandra.

I will develop many websites on Cassandra, since I need the scalability (If start with Cassandra from early development, I dont need to think about migration to Cassandra)

But a new website must be less visitor, so I need many database (probably hundreds) running on a machine.

In MySQL, I just need:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
CREATE DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

I've tried looking at Cassandra documentation to create many database in one server, but nothing found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bin/cassandra-cli
create keyspace dbname;

but, if you want "many database running on one machine" instead of "one database running on many machines" then you probably don't need Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra doesn't have anything called 'database', so searching for this term won't help much.

You can have multiple Keyspaces on one Cassandra cluster (though this is unusual).

You can also have multiple Column Families within a Keyspace. This is very normal, and you could use this mechanism to partition data for hundreds of different websites.

However, as jbellis says, Cassandra is designed for massive scalability across a cluster of machines.